# MySQL,JDBC query execution too long

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've got database querying that has become too slow with my current implementation. I need to get all movies from a database and for each of these movies i need their file data from another table. So for each movie i am doing another query. For each candidate entry i need to do a comparison to every movie in the database. Should this be taking 5-10 seconds to execute for approximately 500 candidates?

```
// get movies with all their versions
private ArrayList<Movie> getDatabaseMovies(Connection conn) throws Exception {
    PreparedStatement getMoviesStmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT movieid, title FROM movies", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    ArrayList<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    try {
        ResultSet rs = getMoviesStmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Movie movie = new Movie(rs.getString(2), getDatabaseMovieFiles(conn, rs.getInt(1)));
            movies.add(movie);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        getMoviesStmt.close();
    }
    return movies;
}

public ArrayList<MovieFile> getDatabaseMovieFiles(Connection conn, int movieID) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<MovieFile> movieFiles = new ArrayList<MovieFile>();
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT filename, size, hash, directory FROM file_video WHERE movieid = ?");
    try {
        stmt.setInt(1, movieID);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            MovieFile movieFile = new MovieFile(rs.getString(1), rs.getLong(2), rs.getBytes(3), rs.getString(4));
            movieFiles.add(movieFile);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        stmt.close();
    }

    return movieFiles;
}
```

Comment: The idea of a prepared statement is that we *prepare* a *statement* once and *reuse* it with different values.

Comment: I don't want to sound overly harsh or flippant, but this is some _really_ basic stuff.  Maybe some sort of "introduction to relational databases" is in order? There are plenty of excellent free resources out there.  I fear that even though you will get the correct answer here, you will still be missing a lot of the foundation you will eventually need.

Comment: I guess add 'patronizing', I also didn't want to sound patronizing.

Comment: @Dmitri, Based on my question what foundational material do you recommend I lookup in particular?

Comment: based on your question? I'd say anything that covers RDBMS theory, a solid SQL tutorial, and an intro book on relational design. There are lots and lots of threads on SO with great recommendations for all of those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should this be taking 5-10 seconds to execute for approximately 500 candidates?

Probably not.

There are two ways to improve this:

- Make sure that there is an index on the `movieid` column of `file_video`.
- Combine the two queries into one by using a `JOIN`.

You probably should do both.

Comment: I've got this: "SELECT M.movieid, M.title, MF.filename, MF.size, MF.hash, MF.directory FROM movies M, file_video MF WHERE M.movieid = MF.movieid" now i guess i just need to put some java logic around it to give me what i want.